# Xamarin Android WebAuthenticator bug

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.essentials, webauthenticator

Im having a problem using WebAuthenticator on Xamarin.Android

Everytime i try to log in via a external service (Goverment From Brazil) it returns me Java.Lang.RuntimeException: 'Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo

Heres the class that implements the WebAuthenticatorCallbackActivity:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace TesouroDiretoMobile.Configuration.Droid
{
    [Activity(NoHistory = true, LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop, Exported = true, Name = "br.gov.fazenda.tesouro.td.CallBackActivity", Label = "TesouroDireto")]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionView },
        Categories = new[] { Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault, Android.Content.Intent.CategoryBrowsable },
        DataScheme = "tesourodireto://retornologinunico")]
    public class AutenticadorGovBr : Xamarin.Essentials.WebAuthenticatorCallbackActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }
    }
}
```

My android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:installLocation="auto" package="br.gov.fazenda.tesouro.td" android:versionName="2.3.13" android:versionCode="10826">
    <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="false" android:xlargeScreens="false" android:largestWidthLimitDp="840" />
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="30" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <application android:label="Tesouro Direto" android:theme="@style/MyTheme" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:largeHeap="true" android:allowBackup="true">
        <!-- largeHeap utilizado devido a problemas encontrados no uso do plugin fingerprint -->
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon" android:resource="@drawable/icon" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color" android:resource="@color/primary" />
        <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver" android:exported="false" />
        <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <activity android:name="br.gov.fazenda.tesouro.td.CallBackActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="tesourodireto" android:host="retornologinunico" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

The call for the authenticator

```
var uriBuilder = new StringBuilder(AppSettings.SegurancaBaseAddress);

                uriBuilder.Append("/authorize");
                uriBuilder.Append($"?response_type={AppSettings.ResponseType}");
                uriBuilder.Append($"&client_id={Criptografia.Descriptografar(AppSettings.ClientId)}");
                uriBuilder.Append($"&scope={AppSettings.Scope}");
                uriBuilder.Append($"&redirect_uri={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(AppSettings.RedirectUri,Encoding.UTF8)}");
                uriBuilder.Append($"&nonce={Guid.NewGuid()}");
                uriBuilder.Append($"&state={Guid.NewGuid()}");

                var authResult = await Xamarin.Essentials.WebAuthenticator.AuthenticateAsync(
                    new Uri(uriBuilder.ToString()),
                    new Uri(AppSettings.RedirectUri));

                var accessToken = authResult?.Properties["code"];

                await IniciarSessaoGovBr(accessToken, string.Empty);
```

It only happens in android, IOS it works fine

I already tryed updating the packages, changing the name, recreating it all on other branch, and the error keeps ocurring

Comment: Why are you manually adding Activity entries in your manifest? It is already handled by the `Activity` attribute on your `AutenticadorGovBr` class. Having both is probably what is causing issues.

Comment: I tryed removing the activity from the manifest, and now the browser wont open

Comment: Yeah, because your intent filter on the Activity are wrong.

Comment: Ok, what is wrong about it? Im trying to fix it, but i couldnt do anything to make it work

Comment: The scheme and host doesn't match what you had in the manifest before

Comment: Yeah after some time i made it look equal to the manifest, and it worked, but when i tried to archive it and put on a appcenter, im now receiving android.view.inflateException when hes trying to inflate android.widget.TextView, do you know something about that?